# How to free the memory of one element in a HashSet?

Tags: java, memory-management, java.util.scanner, hashset

If I had a code like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();   //an integer
        int q = scanner.nextInt();   //an integer less than or equal to n
 
        Set<String> map = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String input = scanner.next();
            map.add(input);
        }
 
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            String input= scanner.next();
            if (whitelist.contains(input)) {
                //code I want to improve on
                map.remove(input);
                System.out.println("accept");
            } else {
                System.out.println("reject");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After removing the element from the hashset in the second for-loop, will the memory held there be freed? If not, what do I do to actually free it to get more memory I could allocate?

Also, is it possible to free the input from the scanner immediately after it's used? Like freeing the input from the second for-loop after printing out 'accept' or 'reject' so that it doesn't take up memory?

I already searched for ways to free memory, but the only thing I found is using the .clear() function that removes all entries in a map, which I don't want.

Comment: You can't directly free managed memory in Java. You can make it eligible for garbage collection, and the garbage collector will free it *at some point*.

Comment: The JVM knows when to free memory ... and it doesn't need your help to make it happen.  Indeed, if you try to help it, you will **most likely** make things worse, either in a small way or a big way.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

> what do I do to actually free it to get more memory I could allocate

Nothing. You do nothing to specifically free memory.

In Java, you do not directly manage memory. There is no [`malloc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) in Java for you to reverse, nor any [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) for you to track.

When an object has no more references pointing to it, it becomes a candidate for eventual garbage collection. Memory will be freed up later, according to the rules of your JVM’s particular garbage collector implementation.

## Details

In your particular code, each of your `String` objects has only three references:

- `input` reference variable in first `for` loop.
- `input` reference variable in second `for` loop.
- As an element in your `Set`.

The first two, the `input` reference variables, both go out of scope when exiting each loop of their respective `for` loop. So those two references to your string are cleared from memory immediately, when cleared from the stack.

The third reference to each `String` object of interest is stored within the `Set`. When you call [`Map#remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#remove(java.lang.Object)), that element, that reference to your `String` object, is removed from the `Map` collection (assuming your particular concrete implementation of `Map` supports removal — `HashSet` does support removal).

After calling `Map#remove`, you are left with zero references to your `String` object. With no references left pointing to an object, such as `String` object, that object becomes a candidate for garbage collection. Eventually, if your app runs long enough, the [garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) in your [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) will free up the RAM where that object lives.

Also, if the reference to your `Map` goes out of scope, then the map becomes a candidate for garbage collection. When that map is cleared, its contained elements, the contained references, are cleared from memory. Similar to above, with the last reference to your `String` object eradicated, the `String` object becomes a candidate for eventual garbage collection.

Lastly, if your app ends, as seen with your `main` method exiting, then all the memory used by your app is cleared, with all the references and objects instantly wiped away.

---

An exception to the above discussion… `String` is a special type in Java. Some string objects may be [interned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) in a special pool. Interning means a particular string might be recycled from previous use rather than newly instantiated, and may be retained for future use rather than garbage-collected. Interning is possible because each `String` object is [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). This interning behavior varies as an implementation detail of a particular JVM.